# Why the operator $T$ is positive and self-adjoint, which $(T(t)f)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)^{-t}c_{n}z^n$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, self-adjoint-operators

Let $\mathscr{H}=\{f:\mathbb{D}\to \mathbb{C}| f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_{n}z^n, \Vert f\Vert =\sum_{n}\vert c_{n}\vert^2 < \infty\}$. We define $$(T(t)f)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)^{-t}c_{n}z^n.$$

Why is the operator $T$ positive and self-adjoint?

We assume the inter-product is $$(\sum c_{n}z^n, \sum d_{n}z^n)=\sum_{i+j=n}c_{i}\overline{d_{j}}z^n.$$
I do not know what is the self-adjoint of $T$?

If $T$ is self-adjoint, and $$(T(t)f,f)=\sum_{i+j=n}\frac{c_{i}\bar{c_{j}}}{(i+1)^t}\geq 0,$$
which inply the positive.

Comment: The question doesn't make much sense unless you say what innter product you have in mind.

Comment: Hmm, it makes less sense than I realized. Did you mean to ask why $T(t)$ is positive? That last sum is not $(Tf,f)$, it is $(T(t)f,f)$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Yes, you're right! Thanks, I have edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written the question makes little sense. The inner product should be a number, but as written it seems to be a function (and, in that case, the formula as written cannot be right).

I will assume that the inner product is 
$$
\langle \sum_n c_nz^n,\sum_nd_nz^n\rangle=\sum_n c_n\overline{d_n}
$$
(this makes $\mathcal H$ a Hilbert space as it is actually $\ell^2(\mathbb N)$ in disguise). 
In that case, you have 
$$
\langle T(t)f,f\rangle=\sum_n\frac{|c_n|^2}{(n+1)^t}\geq0. 
$$
Since the Hilbert space is complex, this is enough to imply that $T(t)$ is selfadjoint (because $\langle T(t)f,f\rangle$ is real), and that $T(t)$ is positive.

Comment: Do you mean that we have $<T(t)f,g>=\overline{<T(t)f,g>}=<T^{*}(t)f,g>$?

Comment: I wouldn't write it in that order, but yes. If $\langle Tx,x\rangle\in\mathbb R$ for all $x$, then $T=T^*$. That's a basic fact about (complex) Hilbert spaces.